# Memory allocated using cudaMalloc shows up as `?? ?? ??`

Tags: c++, memory, cuda

I downloaded NVIDIA Computing Toolkit (containing CUDA 9.0 SDK). Inside the SDK, there is a Visual Studio project called `cppIntegration`.

In `cppIntegration` project, there are variables with type `char*`that are allocated memory using `cudaMalloc()` and then data is copied to these variables using `cudaMemcpy()`. While debugging the project in Visual Studio I can see the memory address pointed by the `char*` variable but when I try to read that memory using the memory window in the debugger I just see `?? ?? ??` repeatedly.

The `.cu` file in the `cppIntegration` project is as follows (only showing code relevant to the question):

```
extern "C" bool
runTest(const int argc, const char **argv, char *data, int2 *data_int2, unsigned int len)
{
    // use command-line specified CUDA device, otherwise use device with highest Gflops/s
    findCudaDevice(argc, (const char **)argv);

    const unsigned int num_threads = len / 4;
    assert(0 == (len % 4));
    const unsigned int mem_size = sizeof(char) * len;
    const unsigned int mem_size_int2 = sizeof(int2) * len;

    // allocate device memory
    char *d_data;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **) &d_data, mem_size));
    // copy host memory to device
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, mem_size,
                               cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

`runTest()` is called from `main()`.

I tried viewing data pointed by `d_data` but it shows up as `?? ?? ??`. **How do I view the actual memory data pointed by the `char*`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't view this memory in the host (= CPU) debugger. `cudaMalloc` allocates device (= GPU) memory, so the pointer returned points into GPU memory and makes no sense whatsoever on the host. From the host's point of view, a device-memory pointer is just a black-box value. Only device code can dereference that.

To be able to view contents of device memory when debugging, you have to use a device debugger (such as NSight or cuda-gdb) and put a breakpoint in device code. I have no experience with this, though, so I cannot provide more info.

If you want to view such memory on the host, you have to copy it into host memory. That's what `cudaMemcpy(..., cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)` and similar functions do.

Comment: For debugging purposes, do people usually copy the memory from device to host so they can view it? Could you please include how I would accomplish this? I thought I could view the device memory because I read [this](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.0/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/View_Memory.htm) but I guess the memory I'm trying to read is not global, shared, or local?

Comment: If you use the device code debugging feature of Nsight VSE, and set a breakpoint in device code (and hit/stop at that breakpoint), I believe you should be able to inspect device data at that point.

Comment: Using `cuda-gdb` one can access memory by casting it as `(@global char *) data`. Might not be useful in this case since its Windows platform though